# When is it acceptable to rollback an edit on an answer when the answerer edits drastically?

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

I was having a [discussion](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/when-is-it-acceptable-to-rollback-an-edit-on-an-answer-when-the-answerer-edits-dr) with [bjb568](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2371861/bjb568) in the [meta tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) about this and we are on opposite sides.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5718398/774078

This link only answer, I argued is salvageable through edits, while he argued that such an edit would be invalid, and subject to being rolled back.

If an answer poster edits a low quality answer (link only in this case), is it subject to rollback because of the drastic changes?

Important note: the edit to the answer we are to assume in this hypothetical but could easily happen situation is that the SAME PERSON that posted the answer makes the edit.

Comment: Well, if it was a _suggested_ edit it might be rejected for being too drastic.

Comment: @SantaClaus yes, but the context here is that the same poster edits such a question, and it gets rolled back by another user. If some other user made such an edit it would most definitely be rolled back as invalid

Comment: If the answerer edits their own answer, then it shouldn't be rolled back...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make it a good answer, based on the linked content, while properly attributing the source (possibly by simply leaving the links intact) and not violating possible licenses, I don't really see the problem.

Granted, if you do so as a lower rep user, the review process might see your suggested edit rejected because of a drastic change (OMG so much new content). But as a higher rep user that's not an issue. And a rollback I would only use if the edits were problematic.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean if the same person who posted the answer makes the edit, or somebody else?

Comment: *Based* on the linked content or *quoting* it?

Comment: @SterlingArcher either one. I don't see a major difference there. If someone else were to change the answer (i.e. not base it on the linked content) then that would be problematic in my opinion. But if you keep it essentially the same, I don't necessarily see a problem.

Comment: @bjb568 Either would work up to a point. If it's a couple of sentences, a quote might work. But I'd personally prefer a "based on" answer with clear attribution of the sources that inspired it.

Comment: @Bart Huh. I was under the impression that you shouldn't make changes to the meaning of posts when editing, only mistakes in them (spelling, grammar, formatting, clarifying if they're doing a bad job of conveying their message).

Comment: @bjb568 if you actually change what the answer is, then that's a problem. But the point here is (correct me if I'm wrong) including actual content from the linked sources into the post. I.e. you're not really changing what the answer is, just the location of where to find it.

Comment: I haven't checked the question but if any of the SO's links provide the answer to the question, it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Bart But you're not copy pasting the whole page, so content is lost. Isn't that changing the post?

Comment: ... I don't really follow what you're getting at @bjb568. I'd only suggest distilling the external information down to a point where the SO post can stand on its own. (i.e. where you wouldn't find it necessary to delete it any more)

Comment: @Bart But everybody has different opinions on what content is relevant, what should remain in the answer after distilling it. So *you* can't distill it.

Comment: That's getting rather esoteric @bjb568 ... If you find an answer with just links (and let's assume it doesn't lead to a duplicate), and you can establish that does indeed answer the question asked, is it then really impossible to get a bare minimum of information into the post on SO that makes it self-contained, yet still properly attributes the original source?

Comment: @Bart I guess it's possible. Tho there can be disputes about what should be included. But I've never seen somebody edit like that before.

Comment: @bjb568 me neither, but that doesn't necessarily make it a problem. But then again, it's just my view. For all you know I might be insane ... :p

Comment: @Bart We *definitely* know that you're insane… :P

Comment: @bjb568 Flagged as "sad but true"!